# Android - View.requestLayout doesn't work in OnLayoutChangeListener

Tags: java, android, layout, viewgroup

I have to use the `GridLayout` for my application. The problem of `GridLayout` is the limitation of weight so I must scale its children size at runtime. I do this by the help of an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

The children of my `GridLayout` are two `Button`s which have got the width of the parent and the half of parents height. One `Button` above and one `Button` below.
If the upper `Button` is clicked I want to switch the size of the `GridLayout` to 500 in width and height and 700 in width and height.
After the click at the upper `Button` the `Button`s should scale correctly but they don't do that.

```java
public class HauptAktivitaet extends Activity implements OnLayoutChangeListener, OnClickListener{

  /** ContentView its sizes I will change on a click later */

  private GridLayout mGridLayout;

  /** LayoutParams of the above child */

  private GridLayout.LayoutParams mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above;

  /** LayoutParams of the below child */

  private GridLayout.LayoutParams mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below;

  /** Children of the ContentView */

  private Button mButtonAbove;
  private Button mButtonBelow;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    inline();

    setContentView(mGridLayout);

  }

  private void inline(){

    /* instantiation of ContentView which is named mGridLayout */

    mGridLayout = new GridLayout(this);

    /* set the count of rows and columns of ContentView */

    mGridLayout.setRowCount(2);
    mGridLayout.setColumnCount(1);

      /* set OnGlobalLayoutListener for observe a change of its layout */

    mGridLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

    /* instantiation of the LayoutParams for the children */

    mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0), GridLayout.spec(0));
    mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(1), GridLayout.spec(0));

    /* instantiation of the children and setting of their LayoutParams */

    mButtonAbove = new Button(this);
    mButtonAbove.setLayoutParams(mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above);
    mButtonAbove.setOnClickListener(this); // A click on this Button changes the Size of its parent ViewGroup.

    /* instantiation of ContentView */

    mButtonBelow = new Button(this);
    mButtonBelow.setLayoutParams(mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below);

    /* add children to the ContentView */

    mGridLayout.addView(mButtonAbove);
    mGridLayout.addView(mButtonBelow);

  }

  @Override
  public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
      int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

    /* Width and height on this time are known */

    int width = mGridLayout.getWidth();
    int height = mGridLayout.getHeight();

    /* Changes the LayoutParams of ContentViews children dynamicly*/

    mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above.width = width;
    mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above.height = height / 2;

    mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below.width = width;
    mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below.height = height / 2;

    /* ISSUE:
     * should update the rendering of the buttons but it doesn't work correctly */

    mButtonAbove.requestLayout();
    mButtonBelow.requestLayout();

    /* A little debug info for knowing of the ContentViews size */

    mButtonBelow.setText("Own Width = " + mButtonBelow.getWidth() + "\n" + 
                         "Own Height = " + mButtonBelow.getHeight() + "\n" +
                         "Perents Width = " + width + "\n" +
                         "Perents Height = " + height);


  }

  private boolean switcher = true;

  /** 
   * Works correctly
   * */

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    if(switcher){
      width = 500;
      height = 500;
      switcher = false;
    }else{
      width = 700;
      height = 700;
      switcher = true;
    }

    mGridLayout.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    mGridLayout.getLayoutParams().height = height;

    mGridLayout.requestLayout();

  }

}
```

Can anybody tell me what to do?

How can I tell the `ContentView` to refresh itself and its children? I am searching for an elegant solution.

Thank you very much for answers!

Regards! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@user3492470
Thank you so much for your answer. I thought nobody has an idea.

Your “solution” is interesting but unfortunately a little bit wrong. Optically it works great but in the background you have got an endless loop …
You will see it if you set a counter at the text of one of the `Button`s. The counter increases endlessly.
The setting of `Button`s' new layout size in the `Handler` is followed by a new call of the `OnLayoutChangeListener` and this `Listener` starts the `Handler` again and so on …
You will get the same problem if you are using the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` instead of the `OnLayoutChangeListener` with a `Handler`.
The reason is the following. The `view.requestLayout()` or `view.setLayoutParams(…)` does not work in the `onLayoutChange` method, but it works in the `onGlobalLayout` method or in a `Handler` which creates a new thread.
Now the part I really don't understand:
A successful call on the `child.requestLayout()` makes a new call on the parent's `onLayoutChange` method. This is peculiar because the parent's layout should not change again.
However that be, a little if/else logic solves the endless calls.

```java
  private int counter = 0;
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /* Width and height on this time are known */

    int width  = mGridLayout.getWidth();
    int height = mGridLayout.getHeight();

    /* Buttons width and height are supposed to be */

    int mButtons_width  = width;
    int mButtons_height = height / 2;

    if(!(mButtonAbove.getWidth()  == mButtons_width  &&
         mButtonAbove.getHeight() == mButtons_height &&
         mButtonBelow.getWidth()  == mButtons_width  &&
         mButtonBelow.getHeight() == mButtons_height)
      ){

      /* Changes the LayoutParams of ContentViews children dynamicly */

      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above.width = mButtons_width;
      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above.height = mButtons_height;

      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below.width = mButtons_width;
      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below.height = mButtons_height;

      /* NO ISSUE ANYMORE:
       * updates the rendering of the buttons */

      mButtonAbove.requestLayout();
      mButtonBelow.requestLayout();

    }

    /* A little debug info for knowing the ContentView's and Children's size */

    mButtonBelow.setText("Own Width = " + mButtonBelow.getWidth() + "\n" + 
                         "Own Height = " + mButtonBelow.getHeight() + "\n" +
                         "Perents Width = " + width + "\n" +
                         "Perents Height = " + height + "\n" +
                         "Calls = " + counter++);

  }
```

In this case I use the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` instead of the `OnLayoutChangeListener`/`uiHandler` Combination. ;-) The if/else logic is the same.

My original question, why `requestLayout` does not work in `onLayoutChange`, is still open but a satisfying solution was presented here so I am happy.

Thank you again for your concern!

Comment: Worked like charm. I have been struggling with this problem for many hours, and this worked. I did not even need to invalidate and/or request layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem. I guess Android has not finished calculating the new layout when `onLayoutChanges()` is called, and a recalculation cannot be triggered from within the method.
The solution is to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post layout changes to the end of the UI thread.

I am not really sure about `requestLayout()`, maybe replace it with another call of `setLayoutParams()`. It probably has the same effect.

So implement your re-layout in a class implementing `Runnable`, instantiate a `Handler` in `onCreate()` and in `onLayoutChanges()` instantiate the Runnable class and post it to the Handler:

```
public class HauptAktivitaet extends Activity implements OnLayoutChangeListener, OnClickListener{

  // this class updates the layout
  private class LayoutUpdater implements Runnable {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    private LayoutUpdater(int width, int height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
    }

    public void run() {
      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above.width = width;
      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above.height = height;

      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below.width = width;
      mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below.height = height;

      // might be necessary or not: set layout parameters to trigger update
      mButtonAbove.setLayoutParams(mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Above);   
      mButtonBelow.setLayoutParams(mGridLayout_LayoutParams_Below);
    }
  }

  /* snip */

  // add handler running in UI thread
  private Handler uiHandler;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // instantiate handler
    uiHandler = new Handler();

    inline();

    setContentView(mGridLayout);

  }

  /* snip */

  @Override
  public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
      int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

    /* Width and height on this time are known */

    int width = mGridLayout.getWidth();
    int height = mGridLayout.getHeight();

    // post layout update to the end of queue
    uiHandler.post(new LayoutUpdater(width, height / 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

handler is dangerous.suggest use 
`view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener();`

**this is not conflict;**